# Don't copy songs into iTunes folder just use them from file system

Tags: iphone, macos, ipad, itunes, ios

I need to add songs into iTunes Library but I don't want to copy songs into library. While drag and drop just copies all songs which needs to be added to the Library folder and then uses it. So, we have waste of space twice, from where we copy songs and to where we copy them. But I don't want to copy songs into Library folder, I just want to add it into Library and play or sync with iPhone. So, at only one place all songs can be managed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In `iTunes` > `Preferences` > `Advanced`

Uncheck **Keep iTunes Media folder organised** and **Copy Files to iTunes Media folder when adding to Library**

Screen shot provided by @Wheat Williams:

[image: iTunes Copy File Settings]

Comment: what if this doesn't work? I do not have the copy files to itunes folder box checked and it has done this anyway...is there a way of checking the folders included in your library?

Comment: @anna  it does work - if you have other problems you should start another question with full details

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Option</kbd> (alt) dragging them in the library will not copy them.