# How do I play songs (with shuffle) stored on a NAS drive connected to my router?

Tags: macos, itunes, music, nas, mp3

I have a folder on a NAS drive connected to my wifi router with some mp3 files. Is there a simple way of playing them on mac with shuffle turned on? Can I use some lightweight mp3 player other than iTunes like Winamp. I tried running winamp under wine but it doesn't run on my current macbook laptop. I don't want to use iTunes as it will make a copy of the songs in its library. Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with iTunes?

Comment: It will copy the songs into its library. I don't want that.

Comment: Only if you tell it to.

Comment: @Tetsujin, you are right. I found a thread which talks about how to prevent iTunes from copying songs to its library: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22515/dont-copy-songs-into-itunes-folder-just-use-them-from-file-system